# Ember.js and Ruby on Rails: Strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js

I need to develop an interactive web app with an admin backend. I have thought about using Ember.js for the frontend and Ruby on Rails (with ActiveAdmin) for the backend.

But i have some questions:

**1)** **Should i put the Ember.js app inside the rails project, or having both separate?** Is there any performance difference or something i should know about choosing one of the two strategies? I like to have things as clear as i can.

**2)** **Should i use Ember.js and Rails-API instead?** I mean... i think i won't use almost anything about the Ruby on Rails project... But i am confused, as i need the Admin Backend...

I have some experience (a little) on Ruby on Rails, but as i am new to Ember.js, i would really appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Take in account that ember active studying will add 3-4 months to project deadline (my practice), because of the rapidly changing ember api (migration to Ember 2.0), ember-cli infrastructure with many new concepts to learn (if you have no background in broccoli, bower, node npm and etc), outdated documents and searching workaround on issues and outdated addons.

Comment: I don't have a rush with the deadline... could you tell me anything else about my questions?

Comment: If so, go forward with Rails-API and Ember (ember-cli way and ember-data). It's amazing adventure. Use latest versions. Ember 2.0 will be much simpler in concepts, read/watch about it. Stay tuned ember blog (new releases/deprecations), github repos (unresolved issues). Ember power looks great after rails background. But time consuming. Ember-data sometimes also looks confusing, but worth time. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I also worked on a similar kind of project, and believe me having two different projects will benefit you a lot.

I used followings:

- Sinatra for backend
- Backbone.js for frontend

It makes a lot easier to add the functionality in your code, when you use two separate apps.

Comment: Thanks... but one more question... have you had to do an admin backend? If not: how should you do that?

Comment: For the time being, we do not have one. We used dynamoDB by Amazon at the backend. We actually didn't need any admin backend!

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar project with an Angular app and a Rails backend. I agree with Arslan. Having a Sinatra, Rack or other API is better than Rails.

Using Ember for some parts, and Rails for other parts (like the Admin section) is a bad idea because:

1. You are doing the same things 2 different ways: getting data, rendering pages, etc.
2. You would have 2 separate functionalities in within the Rails app: one Rails app and one API.

It is much simpler to run 2 separate apps than to put a Javascript MVC into a Rails app. You end up with complexity in getting the Asset Pipeline to do what you need.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. So, you are telling me that for you the best solution is having the ember/angular app with the admin section included, and on the other side the rails/sinatra API?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you restrict the Rails App to strictly API functionality, that's OK. I think Rack and Sinatra are better choices, but a Rails API is not bad.

Comment: I disagree. If you just need basic crud for a backend as quickly as possible, using rails is the way to go. Doing the crud interface with server side rendering in rails will be far simpler than building two separate client-side js apps. Depending on your use case, you could even use a gem to do most of the work. It all depends on who the users of the admin section will be. Can they tolerate a bit of jankiness from a gem, or do they need the same polished experience as your js app?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

1. If you're fluent in Rails, **stick with Rails.**

Yes, Sinatra or other frameworks may be lighter, but you'd have to handle lots of things by yourself.

As for Rails-API, it's a good project, but it's a bit of hassle at the beginning to figure out what modules were removed, etc. You can make an API with Rails without Rails-API. You can always use Rails-API at a later point *if* it turns out you need the performance increase.

2. **Use Ember CLI** for your client application.

It's the golden path for developing ember applications and using third party libraries. The gem Ember-rails still works and is still maintained, but you should **not** start a new project with it.

3. Keep them separate

It simply makes more sense to have them separate. This way, development and deployments of both apps are not tied to each other.

It uses more repositories though, and if you're using github, it may mean you'd have to switch plans. But there are other options such as bitbucket where the pricing is not tied to the number of private repositories

I hope this helps you.